# Displaying the invalid characters in a string using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

The correct pattern for the regular expression is:

```
$pattern = '/^[A-Z0-9,: \']+$/';
```

Meaning, only characters A-Z, numbers 0-9, a comma, a colon, and an apostrophe are allowed inside the text.

How do I display which characters are invalid by using only `preg_match_all`?

```
preg_match($pattern,$text,$match); // $match would return the valid match
```

What would be the correct pattern to match invalid characters (not A-Z, not 0-9, not a comma or colon or apostrophe)?

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is easy to negate. You can just use this inside `preg_match_all` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/zW0mV1/1)):

```
/[^A-Z0-9,: \']/
```